# Failed to load JLink in consecutive antcall's

Tags: java, workbench

I'm using Ant script in Eclipse using Workbench on Windows 7. I've used multiple versions but the issue persists. Essentially, I define multiple targets and call them in sequence like this:

Multiple targets (# below is 1, 2, etc.):

```
<target name="target-#">
  <mathematica exe="${mathExe}"
    ...mathematica operations
  </mathematica>
</target>
```

Calling targets:

```
<target name="callingTarget">
  <antcall targe="target-1">
  <antcall targe="target-2">
</target>
```

Individual target can all run smoothly. But if called in sequence, the second one would fail with this message:

[mathematica] Fatal error: cannot find the required native library named JLinkNativeLibrary.

Searching of this error points to CLASSPATH, which I tried various ways including hard coding in the Ant script and setting in Environment.

However, it would work fine when using "depends":

```
<target name="callingTarget" depends="target-1,target-2">
</target>
```

I guess it has something to do with how Mathematica workbench loads/resets JLink. A further twist is that if the above "target-1" is docbuild (target "main" in docbuild.xml) provided by Workbench, even "depends" gives the same error when "target-2" starts.

I echo'ed "\${mathExe}" and "${jlinkpath}" in each target and they were still defined correctly. I'd appreciate your help or suggestion on where the loading issues might be.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution for it: adding the JLink.jar to Ant Runtime (Windows/Preference/Ant/Runtime/Classpath/Add External JARs).

Previously I tried Windows environment %path% but did not work. It probably could work with some other settings since this is also addressing the CLASSPATH issue.

It has been bothering me for quite some time but I can't get around it any more. I'm not sure what really is going on but maybe future Workbench will fix this.